# VSCode shortcut to select ALL values inside quotes, and then replace a ton of repeated values?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I basically have to modify a 2,000+ line PHP file.

I have to replace all the 'null' values, with the original paremeter with a $ at the start. Now, by manually doing it line by line will take forever. Is there a shortcut or extension I can use to automate this for me?

This is a small block of code which I have:

```
'SecuredLoanDetails' => array(
                    'ExitStrategy' => null,
                    'ChangeOfUseRequired' => null,
                    'ProjectRequiresPlanning' => null,
                    'ProjectPlanningGranted' => null,
                    'BridgingDetails' => array(
                        'BridgingPaymentMethod' => 'RolledUp',
                        'PropertyPreviouslyBridged' => null,
                        'NumberOfMonthsSincePropertyBridged' => null,
                        'BridgingLoanPurpose' => 'First_Charge',
                        'OccupiedByClientOrFamilyMember' => null,
                        'LimitedCompany' => null,
                        'BridgingPropertyUse' => null,
                        'BridgingRefurbishmentType' => null,
                        'BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalValue' => null,
                        'BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalOutstanding' => null,
                    ),
                ),
```

This is what I want:

```
'SecuredLoanDetails' => array(
                    'ExitStrategy' => $ExitStrategy,
                    'ChangeOfUseRequired' => $ChangeOfUseRequired,
                    'ProjectRequiresPlanning' => $ProjectRequiresPlanning,
                    'ProjectPlanningGranted' => $ProjectPlanningGranted,
                    'BridgingDetails' => array(
                        'BridgingPaymentMethod' => 'RolledUp',
                        'PropertyPreviouslyBridged' => $PropertyPreviouslyBridged,
                        'NumberOfMonthsSincePropertyBridged' => $NumberOfMonthsSincePropertyBridged,
                        'BridgingLoanPurpose' => 'First_Charge',
                        'OccupiedByClientOrFamilyMember' => $OccupiedByClientOrFamilyMember,
                        'LimitedCompany' => $LimitedCompany,
                        'BridgingPropertyUse' => $BridgingPropertyUse,
                        'BridgingRefurbishmentType' => $BridgingRefurbishmentType,
                        'BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalValue' => $BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalValue,
                        'BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalOutstanding' => $BridgingAdditionalPropertiesTotalOutstanding,
                    ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with VSCode's find and replace menu. You can enable regex and then use `'(\w*)' => null` as the find string and `'$1' => $$$1` as the replace string.

This works by matching a quoted word followed by `=> null` and capturing the quoted word into the group `$1`. Then the replacement string is built as `'(captured word)' => $(captured word)` where `(captured word)` is the contents of group `$1`.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly! How did you learn how to use that? Is there any good docs out there?

Comment: @DonnieBerry There are tons of tutorials on using regex (just search Regular Expressions). I have been using them for a long time so I don't have any beginners tutorials to offer. I tend to use [MS's reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) when writing anything with regex, but it is more of a technical reference than a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Given your text, you can replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) the occurrences of `'identifier' => null` with `'identifier' => $identifier` using the following regex and replace pattern. Make sure to turn on the use of regular expressions in the Find/Replace box (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or the button on the right side of the Find text field that looks like `.*`).

```
('[^']*')(\s*=>\s*)(null)
```

```
$1$2\$$1
```

This captures group 1 `'identifier'`, group 2 `=>`, and group 3 `null` and substitutes group 1, group 2, and your variable `$identifier`.